# Webstorm: debugging node.js sails app

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, sails.js

I'm having a hard time finding the right combination of settings to allow me to debug my node.js sails application in webstorm.

These are the settings I've tried using, both configurations work (as in sails starts) but none is stopping at breakpoints.

[image]

[image]

If I go to the breakpoints menu and turn on 'Any exception enabled' - it does stop for exceptions, but never hits my breakpoints.

Any ideas? I'm on webstorm 7.0.1 and Node 0.10.18 / Sails 0.9.7

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the --debug in node parameters. Here is my config and i am on 7.0.1 and node 0.10.4

[image]

Let me know if it helped. Also, you are hitting the bug to run debug right? [image]

Also, can you please invalidate caches/ restart? That helps sometimes. Here is a snapshot in the file menu. [image]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it without `--debug` before, it still doesn't hit any of my breakpoints

Comment: I've restarted webstorm multiple times and even tried it on an earlier version (before 7.0.1 I had 7). How do I invalidate caches?

Comment: Edited my answer to show you invalidate caches/ restart. Also, what os are you on?

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Mac OS (10.8.5). Invalidating caches didn't fix the problem, still same issue.

Comment: Lets take a step back and can you create a new project with project type and use project type as "node.js boilerplate", give it a temp directory and as soon as it is created debug it with options i showed. I want to see if something in your .idea is corrupted.

Comment: Good call, it does work on an empty project. Should I delete the `.idea` directory and recreate the project in webstorm? Are there correct steps to follow when doing that? (obviously I did something wrong last time)

Comment: yea, you should be able to delete the .idea directory and .DS_Store file. You should open the directory thru webstorm to let it create. fingers crossed :)

Comment: @Madd0g If it worked, could you please the question as answered. Thanks

Comment: just FYI: here is a thread related to sails development in WebStorm - http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5502076#5502076.

Comment: @PradeepMahdevu - I've moved the .idea directory and recreated the project, unfortunately - I've seemed to have made the same mistakes, because I still cannot get the IDE to stop at my breakpoints, I'm currently trying to choose my IDE and this is an evaluation version, don't know if that matters.

Comment: @lena - thanks, I've seen that thread and tried that exact configuration with no luck :(

Comment: @Madd0g I saw your question and I know you want the working solution for WebStorm but if it doesn't go well with this you can try node-inspector. It's quite helpful but of course, takes a little more time to debug with it because of the additional steps you have to make every time when debugging.

Comment: I've tried remote debug (connecting to an existing server) and it does work, but local still doesn't work

Comment: @eAbi - thanks, I've seen that during my research, it does look useful but I prefer to have the debug functionality inside the IDE

Comment: @PradeepMahdevu - any other advice? I've recreated the project but still can't debug sails when running node from webstorm, only remote debug works

Comment: @Madd0g: Sorry, I cant think of much

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and simply installed sails local to the project and everything worked fine.  Not sure why the configuration can't resolve the globally installed sails as that is the error I was getting, but the local install works fine.  I should investigate further, but I'm lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new project on WebStorm, it detects the package.json file and it will ask you to install the dependencies locally. After that, by using the configuration mentioned before (not necessarily by using sails lift but using app.js directly instead), you can debug you application from WebStorm. Another way to do it, is by using this tool, that works like a charm: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector :)